# Add column to dataframe based on values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, I need to use the first dataframe to add a new column to second dataframe, Which has a value `TRUE` if it exists in first dataframe else `FALSE`.

The first dataframe has State and Region Name of University towns in USA

```
    State    RegionName
  0 Alabama  Auburn
  1 Alabama  Florence
  2 Alabama  Jacksonville
  3 Illinois Chicago
```

The second dataframe has growth rates per quarter. It is indexed on State and RegionName

```
                         2008q3         2008q4
State       RegionName                  
Alabama     Jacksonville 499766.666667  487933.333333
California  Los Angeles  469500.000000  443966.666667
Illinois    Chicago      232000.000000  227033.333333
```

So the output dataframe will be

```
                         2008q3         2008q4         univ_town
State       RegionName                  
Alabama     Jacksonville 499766.666667  487933.333333  TRUE
California  Los Angeles  469500.000000  443966.666667  FALSE
Illinois    Chicago      232000.000000  227033.333333  TRUE
```

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: This one is from the Coursera Introduction to Data Science... I just finished that course. You don't need to do what you describe, you can just perform an inner merge to obtain a university_towns dataframe and then take the difference between your all_towns and university_towns dataframes. Check out the pandas index.difference function

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I have done that already, however I was trying to see if there is a more pythonic solution.

Comment: I understand, which is why I upvoted the answer. But added my solution as a comment in case you needed a quick fix :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of various possible ways to do would be to use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) method to check if the index keys corresponding to the multi-index `DF2` are present as respective columns in `DF1` across both the levels.

Then use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do the assignment operation (*True*) after the `&` condition of the boolean mask created gets satisfied, else (*False*).

```
cond1 = df2.index.isin(df1['State'], level=0)   # Check level=0 and df1['State']
cond2 = df2.index.isin(df1['RegionName'], level=1) # Check level=1 and df1['RegionName']

df2.assign(univ_town=np.where(cond1 & cond2, 'TRUE', 'FALSE'))
```

[image]